# Listening for the CAPS key

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to build a small utility that listens for when the user presses the "Caps Lock" key. The program should start and first display wheter the key is ON or OFF. The program should also listen for any changes, and update the frame accordingly.

Unfortunately, the only part I can get right is in the beginning, when the frame displays if the Caps key is on or off. After that, it gets stuck. Even if I press the key it changes nothing on screen.

The program is also supposed to produce a .beep() sound when the caps key is on, but it only works if I start it with the key on.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("CAPS LOCK IS ON!");
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("CAPS LOCK IS OFF!");

    boolean check = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);

    if (check == true) {
        frame.repaint();
        frame.add(label);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    } else {
        frame.repaint();
        frame.add(label1);
    }
    keyPressed(KeyCode.CAPS);
    frame.show();

}

public static void keyPressed(KeyCode e) {
    boolean check = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
    if (check == true) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you only want to know if the Caps key is toggled(on):

```
if (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
                label.setText("CAPS LOCK IS ON!");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            } else {
                label.setText("CAPS LOCK IS OFF");
            }
```

This way it only beeps when the caps key is toggled and doesnt beep when is not toggled.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track "Caps Lock" only within your application, you can do something like:

```java
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK == e.getKeyCode())
            {
                boolean check = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); 
                // do something here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You also might need to track focus and update state when your app is re-focused.

However if you want your application to track Caps Lock system-wide as I suspect you do, than unfortunately you are out of luck. There is no way in pure Java to do it as this is a very OS-specific feature. Still for Windows there is a wrapper around C-code https://github.com/kristian/system-hook

Comment: Thanks, for the input. In reality, I wanted to track Caps Lock as you just mentioned. After some research I think I'm going to use C or C++ and JNI.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, your code isn't registering a `KeyListener`, so it's simply reading the locking state of the key once.

To capture the state change on <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, You need to watch for the `keyPressed` (cap lock on) and `keyReleased` (cap lock off) separately.

Take a look at this example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class CapChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                frame.add(label);

                frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK && Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
                            label.setText("CAPS LOCK IS ON!");
                            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                        } else {
                            label.setText("" + e.getKeyChar());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
                            label.setText("CAPS LOCK IS OFF!");
                        }
                    }
                });
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with `KeyListener`, as soon as the component it's registered to loses focus, you will no longer get key events, try adding a text field or button to the frame and the solution falls apart

Comment: Good catch @MadProgrammer - I was approaching this as a question about the use of `KeyListener` so I didn't really think about the effect of component focus.

Comment: That's why my solution uses `KeyboardFocusManager`

Comment: Your code worked fine for what it tries to accomplish. But I wanted to do something slighty different. What I had in my mind was to give an alert whenever Caps Lock was toggled, not when the key was being pressed. Also, can you explain to me what the Runnable() does?

Answer (score 0):

After the Frame is shown, your program does nothing. You have to register a KeyListener to the frame:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
})
```

In these methods you can react to key presses or releases.

Comment: The problem with `KeyListener`, as soon as the component it's registered to loses focus, you will no longer get key events, try adding a text field or button to the frame and the solution falls apart